# .NET MVC URL Shortener prjects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

I am looking around for an actively developed ASP.MVC project for URL shortening. I wanted to host something on my server for personal use. I found these but they are not actively developer and running on out of date MVC versions.

- [Shovin](https://code.google.com/p/shovin/) - MVC2 -Last Update 2011
- [Shrinkr](http://shrinkr.codeplex.com/) - MVC2 - Last update 2010
- [Mini URL](http://miniurl.codeplex.com/) - MVC2 - Last Update 2009

I can go and convert them and get them to work but if I don't have to redo something that already exists. Anybody know a good, current MVC project that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing and found this one:

[URL Shortener Project using MVC 5 and BootStrap](https://github.com/diksito/url-shortner)

More info can be found [here](http://www.nikolay-angelov.eu/custom-url-shortener-in-asp-net-mvc-5/).